# Drupal views grouping: amount by grouping

Tags: views

I have created a view, I have two separate tables based on this view.  I used "grouping" to get these two tables.  For the pager its asks how many items I want to display.  I want 10 total, the 5 most recent from each grouping.  What it ends up doing is giving me the 10 most recent between the two groupings.  So its uneven.  I wanted 5 and 5, but Im getting 7 and 3 based on published date.  Can I get 5 for each grouping?

thanks, M

Answer (score 1):

The [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) module allows you to specify how many rows you want to display in each group, maybe it can help you.